# Front-end uploads wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload

I have a wordpress webiste which allows users to upload videos and photos. instead of the upload timing out and nothing happening when the file is too big, is there anything that i can do to notify the user when the file is too big and some how automatically resize the file?

Comment: You go into your code and check for `$_FILES[name][size]`

Comment: Thank you il give this a go :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below solution:

- You should increase the file upload limit in php.ini.
- Or you can also do this with your htaccess file, like below

`php_value file_uploads On
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 100M`